# What's the limit on energy density for chemical reactions?

Tags: energy

Considering energy-releasing devices such as bombs or batteries which operate on chemical reactions and not nuclear (i.e. strong/weak) forces, what are the upper bounds on the amount of chemical potential energy that can be contained in 1kg or 1m<sup>3</sup> of ordinary matter at RTP?

Here I'm not asking for the energy density of known compounds, necessarily, but rather an answer of the type "no conceivable compound could exceed X J/kg because ..."

Extra kudos if you can add insight into limits on the rate of energy release and efficiency considerations.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54791/which-chemical-reaction-has-the-highest-specific-energy

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4881/a-theoretical-molecule-that-could-match-uranium-mole-for-mole

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112634/which-substances-have-the-highest-lowest-enthalpy-of-formation-per-gram